# json data not displaying in my html page

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, json

Trying to get json data from php. I want to encode my mysql raw as json and send it to users via ajax. But in my page its not showing the data. What mistakes i did?

**phpScript**

```
<?php
require_once("../configuration.php");
$con=new mysqli($hostname,$dbusername,$dbpass,$dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
    die('The connection to the database could not be established.');
}
$news_name=$_POST['news_name'];
function newsdetails($news_name){
    global $con;
    $querynews="SELECT * FROM news WHERE id='$news_name'";
    $resultnews=$con->query($querynews);
    $rownews=$resultnews->fetch_array();
    echo json_encode($rownews);

}
newsdetails($news_name);

?>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$.ajax({
url: "/function/news_user_page.php",
type: "POST",
data: {news_name:'84'}
success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
         $("#test").html(data);

        },
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            //if fails     
        }

})
```

Comment: Should you remove the colon from this line?  `$news_name=$_POST['news_name:'];`

Comment: The clone was mistakenly posted here. I edited that here. THe clone is not in my script. it mistakenly inserted here when i was copying the code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

- Your json will be parsed by jquery so it will be an object that you cannot use as input for `.html()`. You probably want something like `.html(data.some_field)`;
- Check the exact output of your script in the developers tools, perhaps some warnings are being echoed, invalidating your json;
- You have an sql injection problem;
- Your error message is not valid json so that will cause your javascript to fail;
- You do not have any error handling so you don't even know if a row was found.

Comment: is there any way to publish the whole json data in ajax result? like var_dump in php?

Comment: @nafizaalam In the console: `console.log(data);` or in the browser: `JSON.stringify(data)`.

Comment: He is not setting the dataType to json, so big change the data is processed like html.

Comment: @ikkuh Not likely, if jQuery recognizes it as JSON it will automatically parse it.

Comment: Hello dear. Thanks for the tips. its now showing on console log. But when i'm trying to add $("#test").html(data.id); there is no result. I  am getting the json data. please tell me the tips. My mysql database has id, news_name, news_title, row..

Comment: @nafizaalam You need to post the **complete** output of your script.

Comment: "{"0":"84","id":"84","1":"btv","news_name":"btv","2":"BTV","news_title":"BTV","3":"Bangladesh Televesion","news_description":"Bangladesh Televesion","4":"\/management\/template\/img\/default_logo.png","news_logo":"\/management\/template\/img\/default_logo.png","5":"Dhaka, Bangladesh","news_address":"Dhaka, Bangladesh","6":"free","subs_status":"free","7":"33","newscreatedbyID":"33","8":"2014-08-21","newscreateddate":"2014-08-21","9":null,"sponsored":null,"10":"0","protectstatus":"0","11":"0","approved":"0"}"

@jeroen This is the raw output on my console.

Comment: @nafizaalam Where are you using `console.log(data)`, in the `success` function? Also you you have an html element with an ID of `test`?

Comment: yes this is the output of this code:
success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
   
         console.log(data);
        
        },

Comment: @nafizaalam See my edited comment.

Comment: I'm using console.log(data) on my success function. yes there is a html element with id name text.

Answer (score 0):

Add a comma after data: {news_name:'84'} then add dataType: 'JSON'

Answer (score 0):

```
$news_name=$_POST['news_name:'];
```

Should be without the :

```
$news_name=$_POST['news_name'];
```

Or even better, also escape possible sql injections:

```
$news_name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['news_name']);
```

Comment: Note that the OP is using `mysqli`.

Answer (score 0):

Define response header in PHP script:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

and set

```
dataType: 'json'
```

on $.ajax() call.